# osmnx plot_graph truncates plot size in pixels

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas, osmnx

I'm plotting a osmnx graph like so:

```
my_dpi = 96 #set to your own!
bgcolor = "#061529"
north = -1.2656497829259836
south = -1.3099201363982285
east = 36.76232691456512
west = 36.71737787067992
graph = ox.graph.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west)
height, width = desired_height, desired_width # (9803, 10000) in my case
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph, node_size=0, bbox = (north, south, east, west),
                        figsize=(height/my_dpi, width/my_dpi),
                        dpi = my_dpi,
                        bgcolor = bgcolor,
                        save = True, 
                        filepath='image.jpg', 
                        edge_color=roadColors,
                        edge_linewidth=roadWidths, edge_alpha=1)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.savefig("nairobi_big3.jpg", figsize=(height/my_dpi, width/my_dpi), dpi = my_dpi, bbox_inches='tight', format="jpg", 
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)
```

if I do this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(height/96, width/96))
my_dpi = 96 #set to your own!
bgcolor = "#061529"
north = -1.2656497829259836
south = -1.3099201363982285
east = 36.76232691456512
west = 36.71737787067992
graph = ox.graph.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west)
height, width = desired_height, desired_width # (9803, 10000) in my case
ox.plot_graph(graph, node_size=0, bbox = (north, south, east, west),
                        figsize=(height/my_dpi, width/my_dpi),
                        dpi = my_dpi,
                        bgcolor = bgcolor,
                        ax = ax,
                        save = True, 
                        filepath='image.jpg', 
                        edge_color=roadColors,
                        edge_linewidth=roadWidths, edge_alpha=1)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.savefig("nairobi_big3.jpg", figsize=(height/my_dpi, width/my_dpi), dpi = my_dpi, bbox_inches='tight', format="jpg", 
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)
```

The figure is the correct size

```
<Figure size 9803x10000 with 1 Axes>
```

but it still gets saved in the truncated version and plotted in the truncated version

if this were normal matplotlib it should create an image with pixel size height, width. (with `savefig`)

However it gets truncated by quite some margin

for reference I've used this with a gdf of geometris from osmnx and it worked as expected
my_dpi = 96 here

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(height/96, width/96))
geometries.plot(cmap = 'Accent', figsize = (height/96, width/96), ax = ax)
plt.savefig('map.png', dpi = 96)
```

What am I doing wrong?

thank you for any help and suggestions!

edit:

there is a small distortion
i.e. dividing by 91 for (my_dpi = 96) almost gets the right size.
Though the direct save is even smaller!

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/759#issuecomment-943582744

Comment: @gboeing thank you Geoff, I read through it carefully, I'm still somewhat confused as to why it behaves differently from when I call matplotlib's plot or geopandas plot with the same figsize and dpi. I'm going through your .plot_graph function to understand. Thanks again for the pointers, I hope I'll get it :-)